# Alignment in pst-tree

Tags: pstricks, pst-tree

In this example, using `pst-tree` package:

```
\def\psedge{\ncangles[armA=.5, angleB=180, linearc=.2]}
\pstree[treemode=R, levelsep=3cm] {\Toval{ root }} {
  \Toval{ Tom }
  \Toval{ Cat }
  \Toval{ Very very very very very long entry }
  \Toval{ Jerry }
}
```

The output is ugly because the nodes are aligned by center, how can I make it align to the left?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [an earlier question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4250/169). Sadly, that question hasn't been answered yet.

Comment: Looks like it's been answered now. Not sure how helpful that answer is for this question, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
\def\psedge{\ncangle[armA=.5cm,angleB=180, linearc=.2]}

\pstree[treemode=R, levelsep=3cm] {\Toval{ root }} {
  \Toval{ Tom }
  \Toval{ Cat }
  \Tr{\makebox[4em][l]{\psovalbox{Very very very very very long entry}}}
  \Toval{ Jerry }
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Four spaces in front of a line of code formats it nicely.  You can also click the 010101 button when you are editing.

Comment: To include code: paste to the editor, highlight the code, and then click the binary-like button. Clicking the binary-like button first will result in misalignment.